# Get list of all resx files in project programmability

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I want to get a list of all the resx files available in the project and their path , by any .net entity (and not by System.IO)

When I open a csproj file with notepad , I can see a xml which reflecting the project tree hierarchy included all resx files 
Can I pass through  this data programmability in c#  ?

Comment: Do you want to get that information by opening a csproj file or the compiled assembly?

Comment: I have to get the file list after the project is published, and the resx are configed as Embedded Resource.

Comment: In fact, I need the list of all the classes which are resx, in order to load them as Dictionarys.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you want to consider only the `resx` files that are included into projects, you have to parse the `csproj` files (which are nothing but an `XML` file basically) and traverse them in order to retrieve the `resx` references.

In that case, just load all the `csproj` within the solution folder:

```
var projectFiles = Directory.GetFiles(solutionDir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".csproj");
```

and go for the brutal parsing.

If you just want to pick all the `resx` files, without considering whether they are included into a project or not:

```
var resxFiles = Directory.GetFiles(solutionDir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".resx");
```

You could also parse your `csproj` files using the `MSBuild API` (you need to reference the `Microsoft.Build.Engine` assembly):

```
Project project = new Project();
project.Load(projectFile);
```